# How can parameter expansion be applied to cox proportional hazard models with random effects?

Tags: references, cox-model, glmm, convergence

Parameter expansion is used in various GLMMs to accelerate e.g. EM or Gibbs convergence. Is anybody aware of a paper/work which implements PX for CPH?